# Using ternary in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ternary

I'm trying to work out how I can use multiple conditions with ternary operator in  D3 (still finding my way with D3).
I have a spreadsheet with a column **legislative** and the values included are Yes1, Yes2, Yes3 and No. For Yes1 I want to color my circles red, Yes2 are pink, Yes3 are orange and No are grey. The code below colors all circles either red or pink only.

```
.style("fill", function(d) { 
    return (d.data.legislative == "Yes1" ? "red" : "grey" || "Yes2" ? "pink" : "grey" || "Yes3" ? "orange" : "grey");
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In D3 it is convention to use a scale for this type of mapping between two sets of values.

In your case, you would create an ordinal scale, such as:

```
let colour = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(["Yes1", "Yes2", "Yes3", "No"])
.range(["red", "pink", "orange", "grey"])
```

and then in your style function you would use the colour scale to return the colour based on the value of d.data.legislative:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return colour(d.data.legislative) })
```

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic D3 for this is using a simple ordinal scale, as stated in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073383/5768908).

However, just for completeness, this is the correct ternary operator in your case:

```
return d.data.legislative === "Yes1" ? "red" : 
    d.data.legislative === "Yes2" ? "pink" :
    d.data.legislative === "Yes3" ? "orange" : "gray";
```

Let's see it in action:

```js
["Yes1", "Yes2", "Yes3", "No"].forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(d + " -> " + (d === "Yes1" ? "red" : d === "Yes2" ? "pink" : d === "Yes3" ? "orange" : "gray"));
})
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, that worked too but I needed to add parentheses after the return and before the closing semi colon.

Comment: No, you don't need the parenthesis.

Comment: My apologies Gerardo, you are correct. Thank you for your assistance.