# Can fill attr in d3 be set via a ternary statement?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What I'm trying to do:
Making a chloropeth map.

Relevant code:

```
let color = d3
    .scaleThreshold()
    .domain(extentBorrower)
    .range(d3.schemePurples[9]);

svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .attr("class", "district")
    .data(districts.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", myPathGenerator)
    .style("fill", d => {
      borrByDistrict[d.properties.NAME_3]
        ? color(borrByDistrict[d.properties.NAME_3])
        : color(50000);
    })
```

Structure of `borrByDistrict` dataset:

```
{
Abbottabad: 16222
Astore: 2080
Attock: 104560
Awaran: 0
Badin: 57344
...
}
```

Value of `d`, in this case:

```
{type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
geometry: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: Array(1)}
properties:
ENGTYPE_3: "District"
ID_0: 171
ID_1: 8
ID_2: 32
ID_3: 141
ISO: "PAK"
NAME_0: "Pakistan"
NAME_1: "Sind"
NAME_2: "Sukkur"
NAME_3: "Sukkur"
....
}
```

Because value of `borrByDistrict[d.properties.NAME_3]` could be `undefined`, I need a default, hence the ternary operator. If I remove the ternary statement and only have the default value, it works fine. I also double-checked each of the expressions in the ternary statement (using `console.log()`) from raw values to final hex value (after being converted by color scale) and they are all fine too.

I found similar posts but they don't help me as [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072989/using-ternary-in-d3) has a very small domain() value and so they ended up with a more manual solution. I have 100's of values in domain(). And solution for the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140428/d3-ternary-operator-to-set-class-name) seems to be exactly what I am doing in my code already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have forgotten "return" statement here:

```
.style("fill", d => {
      return borrByDistrict[d.properties.NAME_3]
        ? color(borrByDistrict[d.properties.NAME_3])
        : color(50000);
    }
```

alternatively you can remove curly braces:

```
.style("fill", d => borrByDistrict[d.properties.NAME_3]
        ? color(borrByDistrict[d.properties.NAME_3])
        : color(50000);
```